# How do I get the absolute coordinates of document in dart

Tags: javascript, dart

I need the x, y coordinates of my document element in dart. I tried `.clientTop` and `.clientLeft` without success. `window.screenLeft` and `screenTop` is also important, if the window, is not maximized and is somewhere on the screen.

[image: coordinate]

Comment: Do you mean document or window?

Comment: Hi, look at the picture. I need the coordinate relative to the 0, 0 point of the screen.

Comment: screenLeft and screenTop only contains the window coordinates. This is important too for me, But the height of the title and address bar aren't considered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get screen coordinates of DOM element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703625/get-screen-coordinates-of-dom-element)

Comment: "look at the picture. I need the coordinate relative to the 0, 0 point of the screen" - Your image shows the document offset, not screen offset.

Comment: Can you tell a bit about your use case, what you try to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as close as I can get for the height:

```
num offHeight = window.screenTop + window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;
```